# Can't add outlets / IBActions to .m in Xcode 4.3

Tags: iphone, xcode

[image]

Why can't I drag it like that?

It does not highlight or what you say and when I release nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on nib files . You need to  specify the corresponding view-controller by selecting file's owner . But I guess you are using story board. So select the corresponding view controller the selection just below first responder in your left side view of the storyboard.

And then specify in the utilities section (rightmost view) select the identifier section (third one from the left .. the one looks like a newspaper). specify your corresponding class there in custom class section and you are all set to go .

Note that this IBOutlets only works when this step is successfully done .

Answer (score 1):

i think you can't because your file owner is not connected to your viewController

Comment: This is might a noobish question but how do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1 Declare an IBAction in .h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController


- (IBAction)sampleSelector:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
```

2 Now Try to drag your button's Sent Events->touch up inside to "First Responder" in left pan. Now you should be allowed to bind.

Answer (score 0):

Try dragging into the `.h` file. Setting up outlets that way has always worked for me.